# Distinct with joins

Tags: entity-framework

How do I get distinct rows based on the Last_Name field when my format is as follows:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        ResumeDbEntities srd = new ResumeDbEntities();

        List<M_Employees> First_Name = srd.M_Employees.ToList();
        List<M_Employees> Last_Name = srd.M_Employees.ToList();
        List<M_Employees> CurrentLaborCategory = srd.M_Employees.ToList();
        List<M_Offices> Location_Number = srd.M_Offices.ToList();
        List<M_Offices> City = srd.M_Offices.ToList();
        List<M_Offices> State = srd.M_Offices.ToList();
        List<S_Emp_Resume> Resume_Name = srd.S_Emp_Resume.ToList();

        var multipleTbl = (from p in Resume_Name
                           join t in Last_Name on p.Employee_Rec_Key equals t.Employee_Rec_Key
                           join o in Location_Number on t.Office_Rec_Key equals o.Office_Rec_Key
                           where t.Employee_Rec_Key == 3633
                           select new MultipleClassRes { M_Employeesdetails = t, S_Emp_Resumedetails = p,  M_Officesdetails = o});

        return View(multipleTbl);
    }
```

Comment: In EF, you all of those joins are pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Newly working with MVC but included the auto number from one of the joins.